# Sitecore Experience Accelerator: "An error occured" when adding Bakground Image to Container

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-sxa

Using **Sitecore 8.2 along with SXA 1.2 rev. 161216 (and Google Chrome)**, when I'm **adding a background image to a container and then saving the change**, I get an error,

[image: Error message]

I went to see the logs and saw this error, I am using **Newtonsoft.Json version 6.0.8.18111** (didn't change the default one to my knowledge),

```
14152 11:18:32 ERROR After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: {. Path 'scLayout', line 1, position 1136.
Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
Message: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: {. Path 'scLayout', line 1, position 1136.
Source: Newtonsoft.Json
   à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParsePostValue()
   à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
   à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   à Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   à Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   à Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   à Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests.PipelineProcessorRequest`1.Process(RequestArgs requestArgs)
```

Does someone have an idea what to do to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in that version of SXA. You can ask the patch from Sitecore Support - use reference number 131168.

The will provide a new version of `\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\ExperienceEditor.js` to fix the issue.